# How would I write this function in 1 return statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm having trouble with writing this Cipher Function in one line. I've tried using the result methods with the if and else statements. For instance I know that the I need to do the else statement first before the if statement buts I could be wrong. So I'm trying to figure this out.
How would I write this function in 1 return statement?

```
def cipher(self):
    string = ""
    for i in self.string:
      if i.isalpha():
          if i.isupper():
              alphabet = (ord(i) - 65 + len(self.string)) % (26)
              alphabet += 65
          if i.islower():
              alphabet = (ord(i) - 97 + len(self.string)) % (26)
              alphabet += 97
          letter = chr(alphabet)
      else:
          letter = i
      string += letter
    return string
```

return string
I've tried multiple times but it would always show an error

Comment: You might be able to do it but it will be totally unreadable. Why?

Comment: The basic idea will be `return "".join(<lots of nested conditional expressions> for i in self.string)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be aware that you will need to follow multiple steps in order to transform the code into the form that you want. Where did you get stuck when you tried to follow those steps one at a time? For example, can you write a single line that tells you what the value of `alphabet` should be inside the outer `if`? (Hint: try rewriting this version first, so that first you determine whether to use the value `65` or `97`, and then do the same thing with it.) At any rate, please read [ask] and note that this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: It also isn't clear: what **concrete purpose do you hope to serve** by writing the code in such a fashion? Questions here are expected to be *practical*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with all the caveats of Barmar's super valid comment (and this seems very [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)-y, which you might enjoy), but here we go:

```py
In [7]: string = "hello my #1 person!"

In [8]: ''.join([(chr((ord(i) - (65 if i.isupper() else 97) + len(string)) % (26) + (65 if i.isupper() else 97)) if i.isalpha() else i) for i in string])
Out[8]: 'axeeh fr #1 ixklhg!'
```

Comment: haha. @Alexander [beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74397346/3888719). -1's are fair... this was too fun to pass up :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with barmar. this is totally unreadable and not advised...

But here is a list comprehension version anyway.  I split it into multiple lines to try to improve readability a little bit, but i still wouldn't recommend this.

```
text = "Hello World"
def cipher(text):
    return ''.join(
         [i if not i.isalpha() else
         chr((((ord(i) - 65 + len(text)) % 26) + 65)
         if i.isupper() else
         (((ord(i)-97 + len(text)) %26) +97))
         for i in text])
cipher(text)
```

Output:

```
Spwwz Hzcwo
```